# Processor 8086 assembly rules and limitations

Tags: assembly, x86-16, cpu-registers

I have some questions about coding in 8086 assembly language.

1. Can you use all general purpose for every arithmetic and logical operation (add, sub, shift operations...)
2. Can you assign constant to registers (mov ax, 1; mov bx, 5...)
3. Can you assign one register to another in all possible combinations (mov ax, ss; mov es, bp; mov bp, cx; mov si, di...)

If the answer on any question is negative, what are limitations?

Comment: Have you even tried to read a manual or documentation?

Comment: Now I'd like to know who voted to delete this question. We may argue about whether it's too broad or something, but deleting a question with three well researched answers is just being assholes about other people's work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we talk about general purpose registers (`ax`, `bx`, `cx`, `dx`, `bp`, `sp`, `si`, `di`), and their "narrow" 8 bit counterparts (AKA, the `r16` and `r8` in Intel documentation):

1. Regular arithmetic and logical operations (`add`, `sub`, `shl`/`shr`, `sal`/`sar`, `rol`/`ror`, `and`, `or`, ...) allow a generic `r/m8` or `r/m16` as first operand.

   As for the second operand, it depends from the specific instruction - arithmetic and logical instructions allow an `r8`/`r16` (and have shorter forms for `al`/`ax` as destination register), while shifts/rotates only allow `cl` (plus immediates, fixed 1, ...).

   Some "complex" arithmetic instructions, such as division and multiplication, are hardwired to use specific registers.
2. Yes, `mov` has the `mov r8,imm8` and `mov r16,imm16` forms.
3. Yes, `mov` has the `mov r/m8,r8` and `mov r/m16,r16` forms.

---

Then, there are the segment registers (`cs`, `ds`, `es`, `ss`, AKA `Sreg` in Intel opcodes documentation):

1. Regular arithmetic and logical operations don't have encodings to operate on `Sreg`.
2. No, there's no such a thing as `mov Sreg,imm16`; you have to go first through a general-purpose register (or through the stack - every code-golfer know that `push imm16`/`pop Sreg` is shorter than `mov r16,imm16`/`mov Sreg,r16`).
3. Almost; `mov` has the `mov Sreg,r/m16` and `mov r/m16,Sreg` forms, but no `mov Sreg,Sreg` form.

---

As for the other registers (FLAGS, IP, x87 FPU stack, ...) they are completely on their own, and generally can only be accessed through special-purpose instructions.

Comment: There are LDS and LES instructions that load 32 bit constants into a pair of registers, one of them being segment register DS or ES.

Answer (score 0):

- Some instructions applies to certain register(s) as @Wayne Conrad
  said. For example div instruction (div arg) only uses AX or DX:AX for
  dividend, AH or DX to store remainder and AL or AX to store quotient.
  (Registers used to store dividend, remainder and quotient varies by
  divisor size)

  DIV CX divides DX:AX pair by CX, stores remainder in DX and quotient
  in AX.
- Yes, you can move a register, a memory value or an immediate value to
  a register **as long as its opcode has implemented**.
- No. Unless corresponding move instruction opcode implemented, you can't. For
  example mov sreg, sreg isn't implemented ([you can look in coder32
  instruction reference](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html)), so you can't do "mov es, fs" unless have
  mov sreg, sreg opcode implemented. Also there are some registers
  can't directly accessible like <s>CS and</s> (Thanks to @fuz for pointing
  that) IP due to security "restrictions".

Simply, the "limitations" are opcodes.

Comment: For (2), you cannot move immediates into segment registers or floating point registers. For (3), on the 8086 you can move data to the cs register, causing a long jump. You can even pop cs. Both are forbidden in later revisions of the architecture.

Comment: "so you can't do `mov es, fs`". Not the best example since the `FS` segment register doesn't exist on 8086. Better write `mov es, ds` as an example...

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Can you use all general purpose for every arithmetic and logical operation (add, sub, shift operations...)

Pretty much yes, with a few exceptions.
The exceptions are instructions that have implicit operands. e.g.: `div`, shift by cl, the string instructions, etc.

> 2) Can you assign constant to registers (mov ax, 1; mov bx, 5...)

Yes for all GP registers.
Special purpose registers like the segment registers can only be assigned though a GP register.

> 3) Can you assign one register to another in all possible combinations (mov ax, ss; mov es, bp; mov bp, cx; mov si, di...)

Yes, with some obvious exceptions.
You cannot do a `mov` between two non-GP registers.

For details, see: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html